# How initialize nested complex structure

Tags: go

I have following nested structures:

```
type PDescr struct {
    Name      string 
    Dir       int32  
}


type DDescr struct {
    MPins map[string]*PDescr 


type P_DB struct {
    MId   int32                   
    MDevs map[string]*DDescr 
}

type S_DB struct {
    TId int32 
}

type Main_DB struct {
    FId int32 
    Path string 
    PDb *P_DB 
    SDb *S_DB 
}
```

My main structure is Main_DB.

In Go I started generate structure initialization and can't understand how to do this:

My latest version of sach initialization is the following which is not compiled:

```
book=&pb.Main_DB{
FId: 666,
Path: "my_path",
PDb: &pb.P_DB{
        MId: 5,
        MDevs: []string*DDescr {
              MPins: map[string]*PDescr {
                  Name: "aa",
                  Dir: 7,
                  },
                  },

                },
SDb: &pb.S_DB{
            TId: 777,
          },
}
```

I'm stuck with `MDevs map[string]*DDescr` initialization. I don't know how correct propogate values.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: you missed `map` here: `MDevs: []string*DDescr {`

Comment: yes, I have several mistakes - incorrect usage map notation (it should looks like this 
MDevs: map[string]*DDescr 
instead of 
MDevs: []string*DDescr

and also missing data for the key-value syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of syntax errors in code you provided, not sure if it's because you tried to give shorter version to give an example.

Also, you are missing to initialize `key` for nested maps.

> Example : `MDevs: map[string]*DDescr`
>
> So `MDevs` is `map` with
> `string` keys and `*DDescr` values, which can be initialized like
>
> ```
> MDevs: map[string]*DDescr{
>               "first": &DDescr{ `fields from this struct` }
> }
> ```

I tried to re-produce your example here, which is working fine: https://play.golang.org/p/Zn8u0f92Xn

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your example was very helpful. It solved my problem.